# Although i got one i got NoMethodError message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In ruby on rails i want to show user's articles. Here is my articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show ]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /articles or /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def myarticles
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  # GET /articles/1 or /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    #@article = Article.new
    @article = current_user.article.build
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles or /articles.json
  def create
    #@article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article = current_user.article.build(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: "Article was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1 or /articles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: "Article was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1 or /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: "Article was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  def correct_user
    @article = current_user.article.find_by(id: params[:id])
    #redirect_to friends_path, notice: "Not Authorized To Edit This Friend" if @friend.nil?
    redirect_to articles_path, notice: "Not Authorized To Edit This Article" if @article.nil?
  end




  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description, :paragraph, :image, :content, :user_id)
      #params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description, :paragraph, :image, :content) eskisi
    end
end
```

in views/articles i have myarticles.html.erb

and in routes i have `get 'articles/myarticles'`

in myarticles.html.erb i have the same code for show.html.erb(actually i want to show the articles that belongs to that user but i will add that later):

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    
    <div style="justify-content: center;display: flex;" >
      <div style="max-width:680px;width: 100%;" >
      <%# <div class="container-{680px}"> %>
        <br>
    
        <h1>
          <%= @article.title %> 
        </h1>
    
    
        <p>
          <%= @article.description %>
        </p>
    
        
        <%# <p style="justify-content: center;display: flex;" > %>
        <p style="flex-direction: column;display: flex;" > 
          <%if @article.image.attached? %>
            <%=image_tag @article.image ,class:"img-fluid"%>
          <% end %>  
        </p>
    
    
        <p>
          <%= @article.content %>
        </p>
    
    <%# 
        <p>
          <%= @article.paragraph %>
        <%# </p> %>
    
    
    
        <br>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) ,class:"btn btn-secondary"%> |
        <%= link_to 'Back', articles_path ,class:"btn btn-secondary"%>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But i got this message:

NoMethodError in Articles#myarticles

Showing C:/Users/oem/Desktop/blog/app/views/articles/myarticles.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

```
 <h1>
   <%= @article.title %> 
 </h1>
```

Comment: If you want `@article` to be available in your view template you will need to expose it in your `myarticles` action... either explicitly by defining it or by adding your action name to the `set_article` callback at the top of the controller definition

Comment: i changed articlescontroller's  first lines as:  \n                                                 
     before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :myarticles ] \n
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]   \n It worked but                                                           now i got message ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#myarticles
Couldn't find Article without an ID \n can you help @obiruby

Comment: In order to fix the error, you'll need to pass the `:id` param when you make the request. For example, '/articles/myarticles?id=5`. You will also need to make sure that there is an Article record with matching ID (5, in this example) in the database.

Comment: I want to see all of it like in index. How can i do

Comment: @obiruby  How can i see all of it like in index?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller actionmyarticles you declared @articles. But in the view you are using @article. @article is available in show where is declared with the before_action callback, but not in my articles.

You probably want to show a list of articles in myarticles view so you can do something like:

```
<%= @articles.each do |article| %>
   <h1>
    <%= article.title %> 
   </h1>

...and so on

<% end %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately i got same error :/

Comment: should have been `article`, not `@article` -- edited the answer to correct it